# PySide/PyQt, is is possible to make sliders dependent i.e. give them a combined maximum

Tags: pyqt, pyside, qslider

In pyside or pyqt:

Say that I have 3 sliders whose combined value mustn't exceed 9 or/and that it would always have to be 9. Is there an inbuilt way to make them depended in such a way, or do I have to program them.

```
Illustration:
  0123456789
1 ---------|
2 |---------
3 |---------

  0123456789
1 ---|------
2 ---|------
3 ---|------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The available [slots and singals on a QSlider](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractslider.html) mean that there would be no way to automatically have them all connect. To do this you would need to create a custom widget or at the least code in some additional logic.